# Json Data not properly reflecting in tableView

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

Loading local json file to table view and in Debugger Log all goes fine but *data is repeating itself in tableView*. I've taken screenshot of simulator and Log both here - [image: image description here] May be i think i've a problem in appending data. I have TableViewCell - viewCell and my data class - attendance.swift and a tableViewController of course. I am trying to display two data fields. Code for tableViewController -

```
var checkins = [attendance]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    jsonParsingFromFile() 
}
func jsonParsingFromFile()
{
    let path: NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("jsonFile", ofType: "json")!
    let data : NSData = try! NSData(contentsOfFile: path as String, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMapped)
    self.parseJsonData(data)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}

func parseJsonData(data:NSData) -> [attendance]{ 
    do{
        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
        //parse json data

        let jsonCheckins = jsonResult?["university1"] as! [AnyObject]
        for jsonAttendance in jsonCheckins {

            let checkin = attendance()
            checkin.id = jsonAttendance["id"] as! Int
            checkin.name = jsonAttendance["name"] as! String

            if (creden != checkin.id)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                print(checkin.id)
                print(checkin.name)
                let check = jsonAttendance["attendance"] as! [AnyObject]

                for ch in check {

                checkin.subject = ch["subject"] as! String
                print(checkin.subject)
                checkin.attended = ch["attended"] as! Int
                checkin.done = ch["held"] as! Int
                checkin.atd = (Float(checkin.attended)/Float(checkin.done))*100
                print(checkin.atd , " %")
                checkins.append(checkin)   
            }                
        }
     }
    }
    catch{
        print(error)
    }
    return checkins
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return checkins.count
}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! viewCell
    cell.subjectLabel.text = checkins[indexPath.row].subject
    cell.attendanceLabel.text = String(checkins[indexPath.row].atd)+" %"    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: where do you reload the table ?

Comment: please update the question with the code and not in comment

Comment: Sorry man. i am now done with my edits you can review it

Comment: do you override `numberOfSections` method too ? or just number of Rows. please add that code as well

Comment: Yes i,ve overrided that too

Comment: seems fine to me, to debug more - i will do `print("\(indexPath.row)" + checkins[indexPath.row].subject)` inside CellForRow method

Comment: This is what i got after adding this -  0Engineering English
1Engineering English
2Engineering English
3Engineering English
4Engineering English
5Engineering English
0Engineering English
1Engineering English
2Engineering English
3Engineering English
4Engineering English
5Engineering English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error seems to be because you are updating a single object only and adding it to array. Therefore in the end you are left up with only one type of object in array with same values

```
let checkin = attendance()
```

move that to inside the loop

```
for ch in check {
```

Comment: Actually i got that bug, i've to store that type array- attendance() into another variable and insert into that loop. But keeping both gives blank output. Thanks man!